# How do I get the publish revision number in VS 2013? (asking again)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, numbers, publish, revision

I've seen this question asked **many** dozens of times, yet I cannot find a **consensus answer** (or any answer that works for me).

My application is run both *with* and *without* using ClickOnce, depending on the scenario in which it is deployed. Here is the problem:

```
Major ...... got it.
Minor ...... got it.
Build ...... got it.
Revision ... always ZERO! <-- I want that number.
```

All of these things:

```
new Version(Application.ProductVersion).ToString()

Application.ProductVersion

Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()

FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().
Location).ProductVersion
```

Yield the same thing:

```
1.2.6.0
```

Which should be 1.2.6.27.

The revision is being incremented every time the application is published. So, how do I programmatically access that number? **Why is this so difficult?**

Thanks,

David

Comment: To help you get answers, you really should show the code you tried so far. This allows people to spot obvious errors or to exclude them from their answers.

Comment: I edited original question. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the revision number is actually 27? If so, can you show us were you see it?

Comment: Daniel, I see the 27 on: Solution --> Properties --> Publish --> Publish Version in the text box directly below 'Revision'.